# Getting Type Error with getElementById

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following code to make a call to another script:

```
function savecoupon<?php echo $r['id']; ?>() {
    var listingid = document.savecouponform<?php echo $r['id']; ?>.listingid.value;
    http.open('get', 'script/save_coupon.php?listingid='+listingid+'');
    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    http.send(null);
}

function handleResponse() {
    if(http.readyState == 4){
        response = http.responseText;
        alert(response);
        document.getElementById(response).innerHTML = "Saved";
    }
}
```

The `alert(response)` is showing the proper results, which is the element id of the div that I am replacing.  But for some reason, when I put the response into the getElementById I get the following error in firebug:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
document.getElementById(response).innerHTML = "Saved";
```

If I replace the innerHTML command with `document.getElementById("savecouponarea1327").innerHTML = "Saved";` everything works as it is supposed to.  How come the response is not being read in the getElementById?

Comment: Instead of using `alert` to debug, use a breakpoint in your browser's debugger to check *exactly* what's in there. `alert` may trigger implicit conversions.

Comment: Just trim() your `response` and see.

Comment: I am willing to bet response has extra characters. `console.log(escape(response));`

Comment: @epascarello You are right.  I get `%0D%0Asavecouponarea1327` output to the console.  However, I have no idea where these extra characters could be coming from. :/

Comment: @JeffThomas i.e new line char. Try `unescape("%0D%0Asavecouponarea1327").trim()`

Comment: `%0d` is the carriage return character. `%0a` is the linefeed character.

Comment: Trimming did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From basic debugging

```
console.log(escape(response));
```

showed that it has extra characters: `%0D%0Asavecouponarea1327`

`%0D` is the carriage return character. `%0A` is the linefeed character.

You have extra line in your server side code.